# Esse bubble sort está correto?

Tags: c++, array, ponteiro, classificação

Gente estou lendo livro "Programming principles and practice using c++ (2nd edition)" do criador do C++. Tem um exercicio la bem no começo falando pra fazer um programa que ordena os numeros dados. Eu fiz usando BubbleSort, queimei bastante neurônios fazendo mais acho que consegui. Queria saber se ele tem algum erro ou alguma situação que de errado, eu fiz alguns testes e parece funcionar. Obrigado.

Código abaixo.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void bubbleSort(int * my_integer_array_pointer /*pointer to original array*/,unsigned int array_size)
{
    int tempChanger = 0;
    unsigned int Swaps = 0;
    unsigned int i = 0;


    for (i = 0; i < (array_size -1); i++) //iterate "my_integer_array_pointer", "array_size-1" times
    {
        if (*(my_integer_array_pointer+i) > *(my_integer_array_pointer+i+1)) // if left number is greater than right number, swapp then
        {
            tempChanger = *(my_integer_array_pointer+i);
            *(my_integer_array_pointer+i) = *(my_integer_array_pointer+i+1);
            *(my_integer_array_pointer+i+1) = tempChanger;
            Swaps++; //count the number of swapped numbers
        }
    }
    if (Swaps > 0) // if swap more than 0 times, need to iterate list again
    {
        bubbleSort(my_integer_array_pointer,array_size);
    }
    /*
    else = list is already sorted, stop function.
    */
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Please type the amount of numbers you want to sort:" << endl;
    int my_integer_array_size;
    cin >> my_integer_array_size;
    int my_integer_array[my_integer_array_size] = {};

    for (int i = 0; i < my_integer_array_size; i++) //iterator used to assign a value to each element of "my_integer_array" with "cin"
    {
       cout << "Please type the " << i+1 << " number" << endl;
       cin >> my_integer_array[i];
    }

    cout << endl;
    bubbleSort(my_integer_array,my_integer_array_size);

    cout << "The ordered array is below :" << endl;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(my_integer_array) / sizeof(int); i++) //iterator to show the results
    {
        cout << my_integer_array[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seu código está correto, implementou bem o bubble sort, porém tome bastante cuidado na declaração do vetor, pois como você fez pode acarretar em uma série de erros. Lembre-se de que quando o código binário (o resultado da copilação) é executado a separação de memória para cada variável (com base nos tipo de cada uma) é feita antes da entrada de dados ou de qualquer outra coisa. Então preste muita atenção nesse detalhe, pois definir o tamanho do vetor por meio de uma variável que irá armazenar o tamanho desejado pelo usuário é uma prática muito arriscada, já que não é possível saber, antes da execução, o conteúdo dos espaços de memória reservados para `my_integer_array_size` e com isso pode acontecer de separar um vetor menor do que o tamanho que o usuário irá digitar.

Mas para tudo temos uma solução. Para usar um vetor com tamanho variável, assim como você fez, é preciso usar de artifícios de memória dinâmica, muda pouco e não atrapalha em nada sua lógica:

```js
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void bubbleSort(int * my_integer_array_pointer /*pointer to original array*/,unsigned int array_size)
{
    int tempChanger = 0;
    unsigned int Swaps = 0;
    unsigned int i = 0;


    for (i = 0; i < (array_size -1); i++) //iterate "my_integer_array_pointer", "array_size-1" times
    {
        if (*(my_integer_array_pointer+i) > *(my_integer_array_pointer+i+1)) // if left number is greater than right number, swapp then
        {
            tempChanger = *(my_integer_array_pointer+i);
            *(my_integer_array_pointer+i) = *(my_integer_array_pointer+i+1);
            *(my_integer_array_pointer+i+1) = tempChanger;
            Swaps++; //count the number of swapped numbers
        }
    }
    if (Swaps > 0) // if swap more than 0 times, need to iterate list again
    {
        bubbleSort(my_integer_array_pointer,array_size);
    }
    /*
    else = list is already sorted, stop function.
    */
 //return my_integer_array_pointer;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Please type the amount of numbers you want to sort:" << endl;
    int my_integer_array_size;
    cin >> my_integer_array_size;
    int * my_integer_array;

 my_integer_array= new int [my_integer_array_size]; //ALOCAÇÃO DINÂMICA DE MEMÓRIA PARA SEU VETOR

    for (int i = 0; i < my_integer_array_size; i++) //iterator used to assign a value to each element of "my_integer_array" with "cin"
    {
       cout << "Please type the " << i+1 << " number" << endl;
       cin >> my_integer_array[i];
    }

    cout << endl;
    bubbleSort(my_integer_array,my_integer_array_size);

    cout << "The ordered array is below :" << endl;
 //AGORA COM O TAMANHO CONHECIDO E JÁ DEFINIDO PODE-SE USAR A VARIAVEL COM O TAMANHO ESCOLHIDO PELO USUÁRIO COMO CONDIÇÃO DE PARADA DO for
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < my_integer_array_size; i++) //iterator to show the results 
    {
        cout << my_integer_array[i] << endl;
    }
 delete [] my_integer_array; //IMPORTANTE!! SEMPRE QUE ALOCAR MEMORIA DINAMICAMENTE LEMBRE-SE DE LIBERAR A MESMA AO FINAL DA EXECUÇÃO DO CÓDIGO
    return 0;
}
```